# Script not importing a class in a separate module

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make chess. I have some code for the Board in a class that uses 'export default Board' at the end of the file. Importing said class in another file breaks the rest of the code, and will not work unless there is no import.

For example:

board.js

```
class Board {
   //code here
}

export default Board;
```

chess.js

```
import Board from './board.js';

console.log('hello')
// will not log
```

Is there a fix?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Importing a module from another one is not a issue and done daily. There must be a issue somewhere else. What does the browser console show?

Comment: There is no browser console. I am on a school laptop and inspect element has been blocked.

Comment: Then this is guessing into the wild an no one can/will help you. Also i highly recommend you to read my posted links. As said, post a MRE at least when you cant provide logs. The most important thing when debugging are logs and error messages.

Comment: Have you declared your script as a module in your html document with type="module"?

Comment: Yes. <script src="scripts/chess.js" type="module"></script>

Comment: Also Marc, what I have provided in the question IS a MRE- the code stated above emits a lot of code that is not needed, and it reproduces a similar problem with the same information I have.

Comment: How do you know your log is not working if you don't have a console available ?

Comment: I used a similar trick where I had an element that I changed the text of. I know the log doesn't work based on how that didn't function.

Comment: NEVERMIND I FIXED IT, i wasnt hosting it on a static server